# Keep failing practicing recursive functions

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have looked at countless examples and I don't know what I keep doing wrong. I want to make a function that prints a multiplication table of 10 (1x 10 till 10x10), but I keep getting maximum call stack size exceeded errors while similar functions written by others who look just as similar run without issue. Can anyone help me with this. I find recursion really hard to understand.

`

```
recursionTable = (multiplier) => {
    let num = 1;

    if (num === 10) {
        return "We've hit the end, my friends."
    }
    return (num + 1) * recursionTable(multiplier);
}

console.log(recursionTable(10));
```

`

Expecting a multiplication table of 10 (from 1x10 till 10x10) through recursion, but after looking at examples for hours nothing seems to work even if I mimic those.

Comment: Exit conditions are important. `num = 1` and `if num === 10` won't exit.

Comment: You're passing the same number into the function as a parameter, and the function doesn't do anything with `multiplier`.

Comment: a) you're testing `num` not `multiplier` b) you're not incrementing the `multiplier` in the recursive call. Also for "*a function that prints a multiplication table*", your function prints too little.

Comment: How would I change this exactly?

Comment: Well think about it: what exactly do you expect `multiplier` to be?

Comment: In this case, 10, hence why I logged recursionTable with a value of 10 to the console

Comment: OK, so what does your code do with `multiplier`? Nothing. If you want a "table" you're going to need to accumulate an array somehow.

Comment: `let num = 1; if (num === 10)`  If I left dirty dishes on the kitchen counter overnight, my mother would accuse me of believing in _kitchen elves_ that sneak into the house in the middle of the night and do all the dishes.  Just as how there is no such thing as kitchen elves, there is nothing that will sneak in between `let num = 1;` and `if (num === 10)` to change the value of `num` from `1` to `10` to make that _if_ condition true.  ...much like how my dirty dishes were still there in the morning.  (Thanks, Mom, for teaching me computer science!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing multiplier with no start condition.
Below code can solve your problem :

```js
recursionTable = (multiplier, num) => {

    if (num === 10) {
        return "We've hit the end, my friends."
    }
    else {
      console.log(num * multiplier);
    }
    return recursionTable(multiplier, num + 1);
}

let num = 1;
console.log(recursionTable(10, num));
```

Comment: Thanks!!! This worked! I finally understand now. I saw so many recursion examples that utilized 'power' that I just forgot to implement the whole formula in there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you make your num = 1 on every recursion, to prevent that you should refactor your code like this:

```
recursionTable = (multiplier) => {
  if (num === 10) {
    return "We've hit the end, my friends."
  }

  num += 1;
  return num * recursionTable(multiplier);
}

let num = 1;
```

Or send 2 values as parameters in your function

```
recursionTable = (multiplier, initValue) => {}
```

And replace your internal num value with initValue

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for all the help! I'm starting to get the hang of it. Turned out like some of you pointed I didn't even include the formula for the recursion to do anything. Now that it works and I've read over it, it really starts to make sense. Thanks again!

Code I ended up using:

```
recursionTable = (num, multi) => {
  if (num === 11) {
    return "We've hit the end of the recursion table.";
  } else {
    console.log(`${num} x ${multi} = ${num * multi}`);
  }
  return recursionTable(num + 1, multi);
};

let num = 1;
console.log(recursionTable(num, 10));

/*
1 x 10 = 10
2 x 10 = 20
3 x 10 = 30
4 x 10 = 40
5 x 10 = 50
6 x 10 = 60
7 x 10 = 70
8 x 10 = 80
9 x 10 = 90
10 x 10 = 100
We've hit the end of the recursion table 
*/
```